# Loading Custom NSBundle within NSBundle

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios9, xcode7

```
NSBundle *customBundle = [NSBundle bundleWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"CustomBundle" ofType:@"bundle"]];
```

When I execute the above code, it returns the `customBundle` in Debug Mode and Adhoc Build. But it returns `nil` when I execute with 32-Bit devices in TestFlight Build/App Store Build. Moreover `customBundle` is added to Main bundle via CocoaPods. And I am using Xcode 7.3.

I am having this weird bug with iOS 9+ only, and it works perfect in iOS 8. For iOS 8 it works fine with all Build/Adhoc/Appstore builds including all 32bit and 64bit devices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue.

This bug because of the key `UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities` added to info.plist inside the bundle by xcode while you build the bundle on 64bit devices.(bundle build on debug mode only for active architecture only)

```
<key>UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities</key>
    <array>
        <string>arm64</string>
    </array>
```

you can solve the bug by just remove the `UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities` key in info.plist or just rebuild the bundle with 32bit device and update the podspec.